# echo command option with os.system() call

Tags: python, scripting, subprocess, os.system

I'm pretty new to python scripting, I'm trying to achieve the python equivalent of shell cmd 
`echo -e  "abc\ncde" >file1`

The contents of file1 then looks like this:

`abc
cde`

My python script has:

`cmd = "echo -e \"abc\ncde\" >file1"
os.system(cmd)`

However, when executing this my file1 looks like this:

`-e abc
cde`

'-e` is an option for echo to recognise \n as new line character and should not be written to the file. Is there a way around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a context manager to open a file, then write your data to the file.

```
>>> data = 'abc\ncde'
>>> with open('/tmp/file1.txt','w') as f:
        f.write(data)

$ cat /tmp/file1.txt
abc
cde
```